# AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode craches the application

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-night-mode

I want to change theme mode to dark like below:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

I use it in the avtivity creation function and get this error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter view**

Considering the activity has some fragments, I think I should recreate the activity and send it to fragments, but I don't know how. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not relevant now but If someone finds it useful I'll try to help.

If You have used a fragment in your activity layout try to change it to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.